# "Uncompression error system halted" on Asus X61SL

Tags: grub2, system-installation, windows-10, bios, lvm

This laptop is driving me crazy.

Scenario:

(not too) Old laptop (P8400 CPU, 4GB RAM) with Asus X61SL latest bios 209
trying to install Ubuntu 16.04

Results:

1. Blinking cursor just after grub: resolved via bios → setting under security → I/O Interface Security → new card interface to "LOCKED" value. I've found this in some forums and it works. By the way, if anyone is familiar with SiS bios and can explain the meaning under the shelf, I would be grateful.
2. System installed with LVM: `Uncompression error system halted` at third reboot. Replicated 3 times. Installation is fine, `apt update` & `apt upgrade` is fine, everything is working until the third reboot. It freezes (last time I've seen caps lock and num lock blink together, too. Not sure about first and second time). From next reboot: `Uncompression error system halted`.
3. Tried another time, system installed without LVM : same behavior except that it doesn't say `Uncompression error system halted`, but it prints a stack trace that mentions BIOS. Sorry that I haven't copied, but I was too frustrated.
4. Installed windows 10... from third(!!!) reboot. It does not find anymore current user `documents` folder and so on. Adding new user replicates the problem to the new user, as well.

Is there any way I can recover from this?

Comment: Tried Lubuntu, same results.